# dotnet publish -o ./dist does not set $OutDir or $OutPath in msbuild

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core

I Have a file move event which I want to trigger after a publish

```
<Target Name="CopyEmailTemplates" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TemplatesFolder Include="Views\EmailTemplates\*.cshtml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(TemplatesFolder)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)Views\EmailTemplates\" />
</Target>
```

I've confirmed that the command does not return the publish directory with this target:

```
<Target Name="OutputTest" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="echo OutPath: $(OutputPath)" />
    <Exec Command="echo OutDir: $(OutDir)" />
</Target>
```

**Expected:**
OutDir is set to dist/

**Actual behavior:**
OutDir is set to bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/

**I am using:** .NET Command Line Tools (2.1.4) on osx.10.12-x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self answering in hopes to prevent future headaches for people.

The `dotnet publish -o ./dist` command will set the `$(PublishDir)` variable in msbuild.

`dotnet build -o ./dist` does however set `$(OutDir)`

To be more explicit with our build I now use the msbuild command

`dotnet publish -o ./dist -c Release`

**Becomes:**

`dotnet msbuild /t:publish /p:PublishDir=dist/ /p:Configuration=Release`

Answer (score 3):

Publish is a two-step process. The project is built using normal build settings and then published to `$(PublishDir)`. Use this property wherever you need to know the path of the publish output.